# How to combine multiple descriptive variables into new variable

Tags: r, merge

This is a sample of my R code that is currently under scrutiny for a side project about academic misconductuct occurrence.

Each `AMC$ExamMC[x]` factor is supposed to be a dichotomous variable with the outcomes of "yes" and "no" for having committed that offense of academic misconduct or not.

As you can see, I tried to use a `merge` function and I have tried using the `ifelse` function to get correct observation values but nothing seems to be working. How do I go about adding an "any of these conditions is sufficient" clause to make this new variable work?

```
AMC$ExamMCH<-AMC$Exams_H
AMC$ExamMCH<-factor(NA,levels=c("yes", "no"))
AMC$ExamMCH[AMC$Exams_H=="2-4 times"]<-"yes"
AMC$ExamMCH[AMC$Exams_H=="0 times"]<-"no"
summary(AMC$ExamMCH)

AMC$ExamMCI<-AMC$Exams_I
AMC$ExamMCI<-factor(NA,levels=c("yes", "no"))
AMC$ExamMCI[AMC$Exams_I==">4 times"|AMC$Exams_I=="2-4 times"|AMC$Exams_I=="1 time"]<-"yes"
AMC$ExamMCI[AMC$Exams_I=="0 times"]<-"no"
summary(AMC$ExamMCI)

AMC$ExamMC<-merge(AMC$ExamMCA, AMC$ExamMCB, AMC$ExamMCC, AMC$ExamMCD, AMC$ExamMCE, AMC$ExamMCF, AMC$ExamMCG, AMC$ExamMCH, AMC$ExamMCI by="yes")
AMC$ExamMC<-factor(NA,levels=c("committed AMC", "hasn't committed AMC"))
AMC$ExamMC[AMC$ExamMCA=="yes"& AMC$ExamMCB=="yes"& AMC$ExamMCC=="yes" AMC$ExamMCD=="yes"|AMC$ExamMCE=="yes"|AMC$ExamMCF=="yes"|AMC$ExamMCG=="yes"|AMC$ExamMCH=="yes"|AMC$ExamMCI=="yes"]<-"committed AMC"
AMC$ExamMC[AMC$ExamMCA=="no"|AMC$ExamMCB=="no"|AMC$ExamMCC=="no"|AMC$ExamMCD=="no"|AMC$ExamMCE=="no"|AMC$ExamMCF=="no"|AMC$ExamMCG=="no"|AMC$ExamMCH=="no"|AMC$ExamMCI=="no"]<-"hasn't committed AMC"
summary(AMC$ExamMC)
```

Comment: providing a small *reproducible* example would make it very easy to answer your question.

Comment: the variables AMC$Exams_A-AMC$Exams_I are all variables with the observational values of ">4 times" "2-4 times" "1 time" or "0 times" i tried to recode all variables A-I into dichotomous values of "yes" or "no" to mimic the strict nature of honor code conduct rules.

Comment: i then tried to combine all of the variables (AMC$Exams_A through AMC$Exams_I) into one Exam misconduct variable labeled AMC$ExamMC with the condition that any value of yes from the combined values would put that observation in the category of "having committed academic misconduct (AMC)" and for "hasn't committed AMC" it would require all "no" values from the combined variables. I apologize for this not being a reproducible sample, but the variables come from an already organized dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge()` is generally used for linking records with a common key across multiple data frames, the way you would in a database. Since all the data we need is in one data frame, we just need some binary logic.

I think you'll find this a lot easier if you try to combine the exam results with logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) than strings (`"yes"`/`"no"`). You can convert [variations](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/logical.html) on the strings `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` to logical. So here's what I propose:

```
# convert raw exam results to binary outcomes
AMC$ExamMCH = character(nrow(AMC))
AMC$ExamMCH[AMC$Exams_H == "2-4 times"] = "TRUE"
AMC$ExamMCH[AMC$Exams_H == "0 times"] = "FALSE"
AMC$ExamMCH = as.logical(AMC$ExamMCH)

# [do the same for $ExamMCI and others]

# combine these into a column that is true if all of the others is
AMC$ExamMC = all(
    AMC$ExamMCA, AMC$ExamMCB, AMC$ExamMCC, AMC$ExamMCD, AMC$ExamMCE,
    AMC$ExamMCF, AMC$ExamMCG, AMC$ExamMCH, AMC$ExamMCI)
```

You can then convert back to character if you'd like prettier labels for charting or reporting (eg. `"Committed AMC"`). If you need more sophisticated logic to combine the binary variables, you can also use `any()`, or you can just use `&` (AND) and `|` (OR) operators, like this:

```
AMC$ExamMC = AMC$ExamMCG == TRUE & AMC$ExamMCH == FALSE | AMC$ExamMCI == TRUE
```

... but at that point you might as well not bother converting to logical, since the equality operator (`==`) can check strings just as easily. Does that help?